# postgresql multidimensional array- extracting multiple non-contiguous elements

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

i am using PostgreSQL 8.2 (i know, we need to upgrade, preaching to the choir).

example:

```
SELECT '{{2,4,8,network1},{4,6,1,network3},{2,10,11,network6}}'::TEXT[] AS X
```

when the X[1:3][1:1] = 2, i would like to return the following:

```
{{2,network1},{2,network6}}
```

is this possible?

thank you!

Comment: It was the challenge to do it in totally outdated 8.4 (I don't know where to find 8.2 so posted it in comments). Hope it will be helpful: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_8.4&fiddle=c00e427791f3c2b2c0389f2f22752598

Comment: thank you @Abelisto! i had to make a few adjustments (order by g,n) for the array_agg and some casing issues- but i was able to get this to work